# Reading A File including tabs

Tags: c++

I have a file consisting of 23 rows. In every row, there are six different strings and these are separated from one another via \t(tab character). In other words, I have a tab separated file.

1)Is it possible to read this file by using fread of fscanf ?

2)If it is not possible, How can I read the file ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sscanf` function:

```
 char string1[SIZE];
 char string2[SIZE];
 char string3[SIZE];
 char string4[SIZE];
 char string5[SIZE];
 char string6[SIZE];

 char line[200];

  FILE *inFile;
  char *inName = "myFile.txt";

  int i = 0;


  inFile = fopen(inName, "r");
  if (!inFile) {
    printf("Couldn't open %s for reading\n");
    return 0;
  }

  while(i < 23 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), inFile) != NULL){
        sscanf( line, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\n]\n", string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6 );
        printf( "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6 );
        i++;
 }
```